# JTextArea regex and ordered lists

Tags: java, regex, swing, list, jtextarea

I'm having a slight problem with regex I'm trying to use on my `JTextArea`. What I'm trying to do it write a regex that will ignore any ordered lists and print the text area contents to the console. The lists are structured with the following conventions:

- Begins on a new line.
- Starts with a digit.
- Followed with a full stop.
- Followed by a space or a tab.

So far this is the code I'm using:

```
String content = txt.getText();
String removeOrderdList = content.replaceAll("^(\\d+).[ \t]+", "");
```

It works great on the first line of the text area contents but not on the other lines. I could remove the "^" but this will effect normal lines that have sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this**

```
String content = txt.getText();
String removeOrderdList = content.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\.[ \t]+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Multiline flag `(?m)` to do this. This makes `^` match the start of each line:

```
String content = "1. rgwfdfs \nnormal text \n3. fdhjsdf\nmore normal text";
System.out.println(content.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\d+)\\.[ \t]+.*\\n", ""));
```

prints

```
normal text 
more normal text
```

Also note that you need to use `\\.` to make sure that a full stop is matched instead of any character.

**[EDIT]**

I just realised that you weren't trying to ignore the lists, but just ignore the first part of the list. So, to do this just use:

```
String content = "1. rgwfdfs \nnormal text \n3. fdhjsdf\nmore normal text";
System.out.println(content.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\d+).[ \t]+", ""));
```

This prints:

```
rgwfdfs 
normal text 
fdhjsdf
more normal text
```